# first element of the listBox c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I just want to take the first element from a list and add it to a file. My problem is that I am not sure why the function "take" does not work, is not compiling because of it.

ListBox does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
var firstItem = Ingredients.Take(1);

File.AppendAllText("Pizza.txt", firstItem + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Why not `Inngredients.First()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Take` will create an `IEnumerable` with the number of elements that is specified as an argument. You are looking for `First()`

```
var firstItem = Ingredients.First();

File.AppendAllText("Pizza.txt", firstItem + Environment.NewLine);
```

If the list is empty `First` will throw an exception. `FirstOrDefault` will return null (or the type default if the `IEnumerable` is of a struct) if the list is empty, Depending on your use case, you should decide which is better for you.

**Edit**

The list in the question, is not `List<T>` but rather a ListBox as was clarified. You can take the `Items` property, use `Cast` to get an `IEnumerable<T>`  and then use `Fist`. I am assuming the objects in the `ListBox` are `string` but you should change that to whatever type you are using:

```
listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: the program is still complaining even when i was adding system.Linq the error which I have is: ListBox does not contain a definition for First and no extension method first.....

Comment: worth pointing out will throw exception if no item in collection

Comment: Agree with @EhsanSajjad - It would be better to call `FirstOrDefault` then check for `null`. However, question seems to be a duplicate of existing one

Comment: still does not work, I was looking at the similar question and getting the code from there, still nothing, is still complaining

Comment: @BogdanDragos Your fist iteration of the question did not mention the `ListBox`, only a `List`. Are you using WinForms ?

Comment: indeed, I am creating  the program in windows forms c#

Comment: @BogdanDragos Edited the answer

Comment: That's because you should be looking at the `Items` property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`:

```
using System.Linq; // don't forget to add this.

var firstItem = yourList.First();
```